# Non local IP-ADDRESS in izpack

Tags: izpack

I'm trying get the IP address in my izpack installer. I have used the ${IP_ADDRESS} variable, but I get the local "127.0.0.1" address instead of the public IP of the computer. Is it the expected functioning? It seems quite useless to me, but I must have missed something. How can I get the public IP?

izpack: v5.0.3
java: 1.7.0_79
Ubuntu: 15.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, ${IP_ADDRESS} is taken as (part from IzPack installer sources):

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
IPAddress = localHost.getHostAddress();
hostname = localHost.getHostName();
```

So, the problem is, that InetAddress.getLocalHost() in most cases returns localhost addresses.

If you need to determine your public ip, it's not as easy, as just to take your localhost's address. You have to iterate over your [network interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInetAddresses()), getting their addresses and determine, which one you need. It's quite a common case if you need to do it not in your business code, but you need it inside the installer.

As I know, it's possible to make your own jar-file and to use it inside your installer, may be you should try to make your own ligic, that determine this public ip and is called from your IzPack installer.

Comment: Thank you Stanislav, it is exactly what I was worrying. I hoped there was a trick to do it easily, but if not, I will extract the IP in my Java job.

Comment: By the way, we had the same requirement at my current project, but we came to the conclusion, that it was too difficult to implement it this way. We just made an input field and asks the user to set required ip or hostname manually.